# How to sew multiple values into one

Tags: sql, sql-server, math

I need to store 5 values in a single SQL Server column, each range 1-90. The values cannot be repeated. I though of using the 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, ... system but you guess it will get really big, using decimal I risk wrong calculation. Is there a convenient way to:

1. store the 5 values into a single column so that to avoid having 90 bit column in the table, [see my previous post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32072690/creating-a-sql-table-with-multiple-columns-automatically).
2. quickly query the database for example to return all records with number X and Y
3. another option was a string (90) containing flags like 000001000011000 but this way I have to use substrings to query and I fear it will slow down on a table with 25.000 records or more.

Comment: `I need to store in a single column (MSSQL) 5 values.`  I strongly suspect that you don't.

Comment: why not you just create the junction table and store bit value in single column with multiple rows with foreign key relationship

Comment: Relational databases frown heavily with regards to storing multiple values in one field.

Comment: I dont understand what is the diffence between this and your previous question.

Comment: This is at least the third question today that involves doing something in an non relational way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved saving the numbers comma separated, then in my code i split this field into an array and can process the data. Numbers are not meant for math operations but just as a string.

Answer (score 0):

**First request:** You say most are bit. But if not all then you cant use bitwise operator. And **can't** save it in a single field

In that case you need an aditional table.

```
Row_id |  fieldName | fieldValue
  1    |  name1     | value1
  1    |  name2     | value2
.
.
.
  1    |  name90    | value90
```

**Second request:** Save the 5 values is very easy and fast on the aditional table. Just create and index for row_id on both tables.

**Third Request:** Here you say again can save it as bits. But instead using strings, that is a bad idea.

Your are right, number isnt big enough to hold 90 bit, that is because a number can only hold 32 or 64 bits depending on type.

In that case you need to use two field (64 bits) or three field (32 bits) to store all 90 possible flags.

Again easy to do and really fast.

**EDIT**

For use multiple fields you have to create categories

Like imagine there are 16 bits split into two 8 bits (0..256)

```
01234567 89ABCDEF 
01010101 11111111
```

Create fieldUp and fieldDown

SAVE

```
FieldUp = 01234567
FieldUp = 1 + 4 + 16 + 64 

FieldDown = 89ABCDEF
FieldDown = 1 + 2 + 4 + 8 + 16 + 32 + 64 + 128
```

Then Select a row with FLAGS [b1, b5, bA] would be

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE
WHERE FieldUp & (4 + 32)
AND   FieldDown & 8
```

Comment: if I use two or three fields how do I query my table for example if it contains number 16, 32, 84?

Comment: Check my edit. You have to split categories. Is just an example, hope give you the idea. let me know if that is clear. But I still thing the aditional table is better.

Comment: I'm not quite sure to understand, how about using a LIKE with only one % on the right most side? I can store the 5 numbers comma separated with a leading 0 for the smaller than 10 would that be still fast enough on 25.000+ records?

Comment: I didn't say anything about LIKE. are you sure write on the correct question?